# Xamarin Start-up

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a newbie in Xamarin. I created a C# cross-platform project, after the project has been created there were several errors I don't know why these errors occurred. How can I fix these errors? When I click build nothing displays. When I click Play my default app does not display.

[image: Error List]

**App.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.App">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you click Rebuild, and put on the question the errors?

Comment: @Tony sorry i updating visual studio at the moment but the errors are in the picture

Comment: Try to use Xamarin with the latest Visual Studio 2017 preview, that has many bugfixes. https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/

Comment: @Tony what is the difference with preview?

Comment: A lot of bugfixes. Also check if there are multiple Java installed on the machine. Run Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: Do I need to reinstall visual studio to install the preview one?

Comment: No. They work side-by-side. If possible, Uninstall all Java on Control Panel, then install Visual Studio 2017 preview. It works well.

Comment: unload project, clean bin/obj folders, load SLN again, click restore NuGet packages and try build again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the Xamarin with Visual studio , It seems there has been something missing form installation. You can find the documentation here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/installation/windows

Regards

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on your project
- Manage Nuuget Packages
- Installed tab : Check if Xamarin is intalled, if yes update it, if not install xamarin
- Clean and rebuild your project.